# Doubt about Probability measure in Lebesgue Inegral exercise.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-integral

I am working my way through the book *Basic Stochastic Processes* from *Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series* and there is a step in one of the excerices' solutions that I can not understand.

The exercice 1.9 goes like this:

Show that if $\eta: \Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a non-negative square integrable random variable, then

$E(\eta²)=2\int_0^\infty tP(\eta>t)dt.$

The solution starts as follows:

Let $F(t)=P\{\eta\leq t\}$ be the distribution function of $\eta$. Then

$E(\eta²)=\int_0^\infty t²dF(t).$

Since $P(\eta>t)=1-F(t)$, we need to show that

$\int_0^\infty t² dF(t) = 2\int_0^\infty t(1-F(t))dt$

The next step and the one I do not understand is this one:

$\int_0^a t² dF(t) = \int_0^a t² d(F(t)-1)$

After this it goes on with integration by parts which I can follow.

Any help would be appreciated, I do not understand how $dF(t)$ seems equivalent to the same probability measure minus 1. I am obviously missing something.

Comment: $dF(a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ . The increments define the integral with respect to $dF(t)$. If we call $G(t)= F(t)-1$, then  $dG((a,b])=G(b)-G(a)=F(b)-F(a)$. In other words the Stieljes integral is the same.

Comment: Wow, how could I miss that? Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it @FOE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$dF(a,b]=F(b)-F(a)$.
The incrementa define the integral with respect yo $dF(t)$.
If we call$$ G(t):=F(t)-1 $$then the stieljes integrals with respect yo F and G Will ve the same because $dF(a,b] $clearly is equal to $ dG(a,b].$
A sidenote: the notation $ d(F(t)-1) $ can ve tricky, You are not translating the measures , maybe that was the confusión.